# The image Loading.gif don't show/hide with jQuery.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a show/hide loading in my jQuery.ajax() request but I have a issue. When I make the ajax call more than one time, the loading image don't show.
I try every thing but nothing work. Finally I try to put a sleep timer with setTimeout and then work a little, the image is showing but when the ajax call is made the image.gif don't work, the animation is stop.
I am using Bootstrap 3.0.0 and jQuery 2.1.1

The html...

```
<a href="#" id="Today" class="navbar-link">Today</a>

<div id="myLoading" class="mydiv" hidden="hidden">
    <img src="~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" class="ajax-loader" />
</div>
```

The jquery code...

```
  jQuery('#Today').click(function () {
    jQuery('#myLoading').show();
    var request = jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Today',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html'
    });

    request.done(function (html, status, jqXHR) {
        jQuery('#tableSection').html(html);
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, status, errorThrow) {
        alert("There was a error: " + errorThrow + ", the estatus is: " + status);
    });

    request.always(function () {
        jQuery('#myLoading').hide();
    });

});
```

The css...

```
.mydiv {
       height: 400px;
       width: 700px;
       position: absolute;
       left: 20%;
       top: 25%;
}
.ajax-loader {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -32px; 
    margin-top: -32px;
    display: block;     
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: looks like the the get request is getting cached so set `cache: false` for the ajax request and try

Comment: Probably your browser may get struck when you do multiple ajax calls at the same time. Your browser may fail to process everything . Usually to animate, animated gif browser want additional memory. According to my experience this is not a programming issue.

Comment: Sounds like you need a counter to see if there's any ajax in progress.

Comment: Where in you html is `#tableSection`? Is `<div id="myLoading" ..>` a child element of it?

Comment: Try adding following two parameters to your Ajax call after dataType,
1) cache: false 2) async: false